# .net Sockets Basic Discussion

Tags: .net, sockets, tcp

I have never played with .net sockets. I did a couple of things with winsock back in the day. The time has however come to make use of some comms so I am brushing up on .net sockets.

Basically, it seems as tho most examples / implementations use the client server architecture where both IP addesses are known. I want my "server" side to not have to know which IP it is going to get a connection from, but discover it when the connection is made. I.e. I will have multiple clients communicating with one server, of which the client ip's will be dynamic.

What is the basic implementation for this type of setup.

Thanks in advance

Comment: As a server you do not need to know the client's IP address at compilation time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In usual scenario, client find the server and connect to it and the server accepts the connection. It's pretty straight forward.

For a connectionless implementation, you can use [UdpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.aspx) class
[This article will help you to implement a basic TCP/IP or UDP application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/testingsocketservers.aspx)

Comment: I see, so the listener automatically knows where to reply to, as it replies to the "stream". So .net is figuring this out under the hood...?

Comment: The socket objects you create represents each connections you make to server/client. That contains, IP, port and other required information to transmit the information. Rest of the tasks leave to the underlying implementation of networking within the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [TcpListener class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx), you just have to bind to a port on a local address and accept calls from any address.

Comment: ye, I have looked at it.. for some reason I thought I had to have the "other" conencting ip. Maybe I was a bit hasety. I will check it out. Thanks